# java.lang.StackOverflowError while cloning repo using jgit

Tags: java, jgit

I am trying to automate branch creation, check out, check in, commit and push using JGit.

While running the below code, I get the following exception. Please help me understand what causing this. Thanks!

```
<dependency>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
              <version>5.4.2.201908231537-r</version>
            </dependency>

Added the below lib to resolve the ClassNotFound exception
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.6</version>
            </dependency>
```

```
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.GitAPIException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider;

public class AutoCommit {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try (Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
                .setURI("https://<my repo>")
                .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("<username>", "<password>"))
                .setBranch("feature/test")
                .setDirectory(new File("C:\\workarea\\test"))
                .call()) {
            git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
            git.commit().setMessage("Testing the automated process").call();
            git.status().call();

            try {
                git.push().setRemote("origin").add("feature/test").call();
            } catch (TransportException e) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Username/Password");
            }
        }
        catch(GitAPIException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the exception stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:67)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:249)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:249)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
```

Comment: Hi dhya!  Do you have a stack trace for the exception handy?  It would be helpful for debugging. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Jamal, I have updated the post with stack trace. Thanks.

Comment: Could anyone please help to resolve this issue I am facing?